# XQuery file : Unexpected char (é)

Tags: xml, xquery

I'm executing XQuery requests on an XML file, but some of its elements's names contain special characters like `<espèce>`.

When I run my .xqy file, I get the following error :

> /project/myfile.xqy
>
> unexpected char: '0xFFFD'

How to get rid of this ?

My .xqy file contains :

```
count(//espèce)
```

Comment: Which XQuery Processor are you working with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FFFD is the Unicode "replacement character", it isn't generally present in the text as a literal character but instead it represents a place where the reader found a byte sequence it couldn't interpret as a valid character.

In practice this probably means your `.xqy` file is encoded in something like ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252 but your software is trying to read it as UTF-8.

Comment: You were right, I was using ISO-8859-1 encoding. Replacing it with UTF-8 was the solution, thanks a lot.